# Как реализовать decal в OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Имеется ландшафт с текстурным покрытием. Имеется текстура на которой изображён крестик. 
Нужно реализовать отображения этого крестика на ландшафте по координатам x,z.
Ландшафт с горками и различными изгибами, и текстура крестика должна в местах x,z так же изгибаться.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Теоретически, нужен `unproject` из экранных координат в пространство ландшафта (в качестве z взять значение из буффера глубины), затем уже по полученным координатам и нормали нарисовать текстурину декали у ландшафта

В голову приходят примерно такие мысли, сам не пробовал, но можно подсмотреть тут http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals